# ¿por qué no me funciona addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy realizando solicitando del usuario un número que determinará el espacio entre las lineas del dibujo, para que se ejecute la función que realiza el dibujo, el usuario debe dar click en el botón "enviar", para detectar este evento utilizo la función addEventListener de la siguiente forma: boton.addEventlistener("click", dibujoporClick) sin emabrgo esto no resulta cuando el usuario hace click sobre el botón. ¿alguien sabe qué pasa?.
En al consola me sale que *boton.addEventlistener is not a function*

```js
var ensayo = document.getElementById("dibujo");
var lienzo = ensayo.getContext("2d");


var texto = document.getElementById("txt_lineas");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
var ancho = ensayo.width;

boton.addEventlistener("click", dibujoporClick);

function dibujoporClick()
{ 
  var lineas = parseInt(texto.value);
  var l = 0;
  var xi; yi; xf; yf;
  var espacio = ancho/lineas 



  function dibujoCuadro(color, xi,yi,xf,yf) 
 {
  lienzo.beginPath();
  lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
  lienzo.moveTo(xi, yi);
  lienzo.lineTo(xf,yf);
  lienzo.stroke();
  lienzo.closePath();

 }

 while (l<lineas)
 {
  yi= l*espacio;
  xf= (l+1)*espacio;
  dibujoCuadro("pink", 0,yi,xf,300);

  yi= l*espacio;
  xf= 300-((l+1)*espacio)
  dibujoCuadro("pink", 300,yi,xf,300);

  xi= l*espacio
  yf= (l+1)*espacio
  dibujoCuadro("pink", xi,0,300,yf);

  xi= 300- (l*espacio)
  yf= l*espacio
  dibujoCuadro("pink", xi,0,0,yf);

  l=l+1;
 }

}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Ensayo de dibujo</h1>
 <input type="text" id="txt_lineas" />
 <input type="button" value="enviar" id="botoncito" /> <br> <br>
 <canvas id="dibujo" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
 <p>Así queda tu dibujo</p>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dibujoparaborrar.js">
  
 </script>


</body>
```

Comment: Obtienes algún error en la consola?

Comment: Si el código JS está en este archivo: `dibujoparaborrar.js` tienes que incluirlo antes, preferiblemente en la etiqueta `head`. Veo que lo estás incluyendo después de los elementos.

Comment: Estas escribiendo mal: `addEventListener`, pusiste `listener`, con ele minúscula. Revida el error en la consola, te indica que no es una función.

Comment: @A.Cedano esta cargando el JS correctamente, se ejecuta en cascada en el momento que carga, si se cargara en el `<head>`, sin atributo `defer` por ejemplo trataría de añadir en *escuchador* de evento a un elemento que aun no existe y ahí tendría un error.

Comment: @Orici no, si revisas mi sugerencia, el código JS estaría dentro de un bloque de escucha de la carga del DOM que es lo correcto, el código JS no se cargará hasta que todo el DOM no lo esté.

Comment: @A.Cedano me refería al orden en el que tiene el JS quien formula la pregunta, es el orden correcto para el código que tiene.

Comment: @Orici MDN es clara cuando habla de `DOMContentLoaded` y recomiendan que no se intente alcanzar desde JS ningún elemento del DOM sin antes estar seguros de que el DOM está totalmente cargados. Uno no se puede confiar en que tiene el código en *cascada*, si hay un elemento que tarda en cargar, porque es pesado, porque proviene de una URL externa que va lenta o lo que sea, el código puede seguir la *cascada* dejando detrás ese elemento y eso puede ser problemático.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un **error de sintaxis**, estás poniendo la `l` en minúscula aquí: `addEventlistener`. Los métodos son case sensitive.

Aparte de eso, conviene que cuando vayas a trabajar con elementos del DOM pongas todo dentro de un bloque que escuche la carga del DOM, [como explica MDN en la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).
También, si el código JS se encuentra en el archivo `dibujoparaborrar.js`, conviene que lo cargues al principio, preferiblemente en el `head`.

Aquí funciona:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var ensayo = document.getElementById("dibujo");
  var lienzo = ensayo.getContext("2d");
  var texto = document.getElementById("txt_lineas");
  var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
  var ancho = ensayo.width;
  boton.addEventListener("click", dibujoporClick);

  function dibujoporClick() {
    console.log("sólo para prueba");
  }

  /*
  function dibujoporClick()
  { 
    var lineas = parseInt(texto.value);
    var l = 0;
    var xi; yi; xf; yf;
    var espacio = ancho/lineas 



    function dibujoCuadro(color, xi,yi,xf,yf) 
   {
    lienzo.beginPath();
    lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
    lienzo.moveTo(xi, yi);
    lienzo.lineTo(xf,yf);
    lienzo.stroke();
    lienzo.closePath();

   }

   while (l<lineas)
   {
    yi= l*espacio;
    xf= (l+1)*espacio;
    dibujoCuadro("pink", 0,yi,xf,300);

    yi= l*espacio;
    xf= 300-((l+1)*espacio)
    dibujoCuadro("pink", 300,yi,xf,300);

    xi= l*espacio
    yf= (l+1)*espacio
    dibujoCuadro("pink", xi,0,300,yf);

    xi= 300- (l*espacio)
    yf= l*espacio
    dibujoCuadro("pink", xi,0,0,yf);

    l=l+1;
   }

  }
  */
});
```

```html
<h1>Ensayo de dibujo</h1>
<input type="text" id="txt_lineas" />
<input type="button" value="enviar" id="botoncito" /> <br> <br>
<canvas id="dibujo" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
<p>Así queda tu dibujo</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizá tengas que añadir el evento dentro de un Windows.onload para comprobar que la página está cargada.
Si no en lugar de añadir así el evento click pongo el el botón aquí puedes ver un ejemplo 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: `w3schools` es muy popular, pero está plagada de errores y de malas prácticas. Es mejor leer la documentación de sitios más confiables o de los sitios oficiales, por ejemplo MDN. Precisamente ellos dicen claramente que muchos confunden `window.load` con `document.load`: *«Un evento muy diferente - `load` - debería ser usado solo para detectar una carga completa de la página. **Es un error increíblemente popular usar load cuando `DOMContentLoaded` sería mucho más apropiado**, así que úsalo con cuidado.»* [Leer más aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)...